# Jquery .scroll() not working in IE with both $(window) and $(document). (issue with window.pageYOffset?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 200;   

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {

       $('.extratext').slideDown('slow');

    }
});
```

That works fine in FF, Chrome and IE 10 but not IE 9 or below. I have researched answers and they all say it should work with `$(window)` instead of the usual `$(document)`, which is what Ive got.

Does anyone know another way of amending this?

EDIT:

Added `console.log(y_scroll_pos);` and it comes up with 'undefined'. Does IE not like `window.pageYOffset;`?

Comment: When you have html and body at height : 100%, sometime `$('html, body')` work.... Worth a try!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MDN docs:

> For cross-browser compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of
>   window.scrollY. Additionally, older versions of Internet Explorer (<
>   9) do not support either property and must be worked around by
>   checking other non-standard properties.

You could always use jQuery's implementation of [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), it should work for all browsers:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var scroll_pos_test = 200;   

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
       $('.extratext').slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```